# Which model to select based on anova table (Chi-test)?

Tags: r, anova, chi-squared, p-value

In the anova table below (produced in GLMM in R), model AAW7 is displayed as the model with the least p-value and hence should be the selected one.

However, in my data the model that addresses my hypothesis is model AAW12.

Is there anything in the table that can be used in favour of model AAW12?

[image: anova table]

Comment: Shad, your question is not related to programming but to methodology and should be posted on cross-validated community instead. As hint, what do you expect from a statistical model that do not have any degree of freedom (case of AAW12 you mention but also AAW7)

Comment: Thanks Eric. When the degree of freedom is zero, that  means that there is no way to affirm or reject the model! So, anova is not the right test?

Comment: Did I just get my question answered:)